# Ubuntu 14.04 and Intel Graphics (Q33/GMA)

Tags: 14.04, intel-graphics

I have just installed 14.04 but I can't get the graphics work. The intel driver seems to be installed, though I work only in 1024x768 and 800x600.

My graphics card is Intel Q33.

Any help plz?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Intel still has no driver support for 14.04, use 13.10 instead and dowmload the intel drivers for Linux 1.0.4